# Behavior of SqlBulkCopy with unique identity columns in database

Tags: c#, sqlbulkcopy

I am facing and issue while inserting data in database. I used a column as unique identity to prevent duplication. When i insert data from excel file to database with sqlbulkcopy, data inserts correctly but when i try to test and insert the same data, sqlbulkcopy commit's the transaction without any error and after this i checked my database there is no update in existing record and no duplicate values.

My question is Why SqlBulkCopy committing transaction without throwing unique identity error?

Comment: Can you add some sample data and the code for your `SqlBulkCopy`? Does this identity column have an autoincrement? If so I'd expect the rows to be added twice, but with different identities.

Comment: This identity column haven't auto increment. As i mentioned before that data wasn't duplicate after inserting it twice or more than twice.